# Equivalent of dd function of Laravel in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to migrate my code from Laravel PHP to ASP.Net Framework 4.6.1 C#.

In Laravel I can use function `dd('test')` or `dd($variabel)`. Which is useful in-order to dump any variable's values with its data-type.

How can i achieve this same thing in ASP.NET?

Comment: In C#, you normally don't want your application to crash even at pre-defined points. A dump-and-die function is therefore not what you should be looking for. Instead, break-points and proper debugging seems more like the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to debug your code (in C# / ASP.NET), and get all the info you need (like in `dd()`), is by using [breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger) within Visual Studio.

You can easily set a 'break' (multiple times) at any point of your application. This allows you to *step through* your application.

Each time a break is hit, the application *pauses* at that point. Whenever you click the 'continue' button, the application will resume.

**Example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger)**:
[image: Example from the Microsoft docs]

You just have to play with this a bit to get the hang of it. But once you know how this *toy* works, you can't work without it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you

```
Console.WriteLine(variabel); 
break;
```

Comment: sorry that code has different function with `dd()` in Laravel @Vajiheh

Comment: If you want to use this command to debug the code, I suggest you use a strong ASP debugging system.One of the methods is the friend( @Matthijs ) suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Using [Desharp](https://github.com/debug-sharp) you can do something like this:

```
public static void dd(dynamic var) {
    Desharp.Debug.DumpAndDie(var);
}
```